# Sum all the multiplications of 2 index matches

Tags: excel, indexing, match, sumproduct

I'm trying the following:

Through indexing and matching get 2 values from 2 different tabs and multiply them, and then summing up all instances of those multiplied matches. I'm trying to achieve this in 1 step.

To illustrate:

1. From tab 'Test_Samples' Match all values in column A with values in 'Reference_Dataset' Column A.
2. Get the corresponding "count" from tab 'Test_Samples' column B and multiply it by the corresponding "gra" from tab 'Reference_Dataset' column J.
3. Add up all results of these multiplications.

[image]

[image]

I've tried SUMIF/SUMIFS and SUMPRODUCT and nesting the indexing and matching in there, but it gives either the wrong results or says the formula is not correct.

The way I index and match to get the "gra" value in column J of the tab 'Reference_Dataset' is as follows:

```
=INDEX(Reference_Dataset!$D:$Z,MATCH($A2,Reference_Dataset!$A:$A,0),MATCH(K$1,Reference_Dataset!$D$1:$Z$1,0))
```

So if "Apple", "Bee" and "Cinnamon" in column A of both tabs have counts in tab 'Test_Samples' of 19, 1 and 10 respectively and the corresponding "gra" values for "Apple", "Bee" and "Cinnamon" in tab 'Reference_Dataset' are 2, 1, 1 respectively, it should multiply and sum up (19*2 + 1*1 + 10*1) to return a total of 49.

Comment: Sounds like you want `sumproduct()` to find what matches then do the multiplication and sum all of the multiplied values... i believe it looks something like: `SUMPRODUCT(--(rangetomatch=matchvalue),multipleby1,multiplyby2)`.  What variation of sumproduct did you use?  post that if possible

Comment: You've posted how is your data, but could you please post an example to help the question? Can you calculate some of them and post how the result should be?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I edited and added it at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array formula like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(G1:G5,INDEX(B:B,N(IF({1},MATCH(F1:F5,A:A,0)))))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I tried =SUMPRODUCT(Reference_Dataset!J2:J363,INDEX(Test_Samples!B:B,N(IF({1},MATCH(Reference_Dataset!A2:A363,Test_Samples!A:A,0))))), which is the equivalent for my sheet, and it gives back a #VALUE?

Comment: Did you use Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode?

Comment: No, I didn't. I might have done something else wrong even though I triple checked.

Comment: When you are done editing the formula in the formula bar you need to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter or Tab.  If done correctly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Comment: Gives #N/A which leads me to think column A of both tabs need the exact same names and no extra/missing (which is not the case).

Comment: @RoddyMacintyre that is correct, Excel cannot interpolate.  It must be exact, right down to the number of spaces.

Comment: I'll accept the answer. It's not exactly how I want it since you need the exact same names in both columns and the exact same amount of names, whereas the 'Reference_Dataset' might include far more names in the future. Funny note: my calculation actually also amounts to 480.

Comment: You do not need the same number of names on the two sheets.  You need the same number of cells reference in both columns on the Reference_Dataset sheet.  but yes the names must be identical in the spelling.  That is Excel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191174/discussion-between-roddy-macintyre-and-scott-craner).